# Getting a file download instead of redirecting to default URL after successful login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring Security with database, and after following an example, I am able to login (`onAuthenticationSuccess` is called), but instead of being redirected to the default page, I am getting an empty file download. 
I am expecting that I am redirected to default page `defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)`

```
@GetMapping(path = "/")
public String displayInitialPage(Model model) {
    return "index";
}
```

security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
private UserService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl successHandler;

@PostConstruct
public void completeSetup() {
    userDetailsService = applicationContext.getBean(UserService.class);
}

@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder()).and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()).jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/register", "/style", "/script");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/", true).permitAll().successHandler(successHandler).and().csrf().disable();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authProvider;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
}

/**
 * Enables activation of automatic resolving of spring-data specific expressions annotated on classes
 * @return SecurityEvaluationContextExtension
 */
@Bean
public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
    return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the security config class as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/register", "/style", "/script");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/", true).permitAll();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That means that the browser doesn't recognize the response, assumes it's a file (last resort)

You have this controller:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/")
public String displayInitialPage(Model model) {
    return "index";
}
```

So, Spring will take the value `"index"` and try to map that to some content. 
There is a lot of magic happening behind the scenes here.

Let's say you are using Spring Boot and you have a gradle build, your dependencies:

```
    compile group: "org.springframework.security", name: "spring-security-core", version: "$springSecurityVersion"
    compile group: "org.springframework.security", name: "spring-security-web", version: "$springSecurityVersion"
    compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-web", version: "$springBootVersion"
    compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-security", version: "$springBootVersion"
    compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf", version: "$springBootVersion"
    compile group: "org.thymeleaf.extras", name: "thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5", version: "$thymeleafExtrasSpringSecurityVersion"
```

Notice the last two lines. These enable *thymeleaf* as a templating engine.
Spring will look in the directory

```
./src/main/resources/templates
```

for a file called `index.html`

That file can look like this:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
<head>
    <title>Spring Security - Simple Flow for Spring Boot Authentication</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div style="float: right" th:fragment="logout" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <div style="float:left">
        <span style="font-weight:bold">User: </span><span sec:authentication="name"></span>
    </div>
    <div style="float:none">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/local/logout}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Local Logout" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<h1>Success</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside Spring Web MVC, there is a bean called

```java
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        ....
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

Spring Boot has a component called auto configuration. So it looks for libraries being present and configures resolvers accordingly. 
There are JSP resolvers for the legacy applications, Content Mapping resolvers when you want to send JSON, XML, or other formats back, and my preferred one, thymeleaf, for sending back HTML content.

At any given time, you can have multiple resolvers configured.

My community repo has many examples to play around with.

https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/tree/master/samples

Comment: I am using thymeleaf. I am suspecting that the cause is a miss-configuration of spring security. I was able to view index.html before I added the security. It also seems like I am able to login successfully, If I visit the link again, then I am directed to the index page.

Comment: I’d start over with the SecurityConfig class. you’re doing too many things there. most of them you don’t need. if you have a sample I can clone I can help further

Comment: I started over and simplified it, and it works now. I was following a complex example.